# web.py on apache gives a Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: python, apache, web.py

What can cause this error?

I get these errors every time a client accesses my server.

it hapens only once in each request.

the script runs with seemingly no problems, but i don't know if there are hidden implications or complication that result from this error that i'm not aware of.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 982, in _setupSocket
    sock.getpeername()
fcgi_base
error: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket
```

i'm running python as cgi ,web.py, linux (ubuntu12)

what can be the cause of this error?

How can I investigate it?

Comment: in recent versions of flup that line is found a a [different place](http://hg.saddi.com/flup-server/file/tip/flup/server/fcgi_base.py#l1028). could you try to uninstall the verion installed (probably from ubuntu's packages) and install the [newest version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flup/1.0.3.dev-20110405) manually?

Comment: i have the latest version (20110405). it's more than 2 years old BTW. (did you downvote me? if so - why?)